# Need a solution with chrome loading images

Tags: css, google-chrome, web

I have an image set as background for a `div`. It loads fine in IE10 but why does it only half load in chrome? It does fully load after refreshing the page.

Here is my CSS code. I am not sure it is perfectly optimized, but it works in IE10. The only problem is the background not loading chrome.

```
html, body {
    background-color:black;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-family:"Century Gothic",Times new roman, Georgia, Serif;
}
#container {
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    height:100%;
}
#img {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:800px;
    height:700px;
    background-image:url("../images/comingsoon.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}
#text {
    padding-bottom:100px;
}
#footer {
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    width:99%;
    padding-bottom:1px;
}
.link a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}
img {
    border:0;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML and the image? Even better would be to post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

thats the fiddle, first time I use it I hope is fine
http://jsfiddle.net/tH2bL/1/`enter code here`

but without the image you can't actualy see what is my problem, you can check it on chrome at www.speakeasy-events.com

the jpg link to the css div img, is half loading on google chrome but not IE10 and I need to refresh it to have the full picture.

an other thing I am not sure my code is really optimized, I think i may have to many div to do what I want, or may be I should put the div #text in position relative to the #img so it stay same place

And with this other issue, you can see that when the browser windows is smaller and you use the scroll bar the div text goes over the img and mask it, how do you avoid that ?

Comment: This is not an answer. This should be a comment or an edit to your question